# Git clone error - fatal: early EOFs

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I want to clone a project from github to my PC with

```
D:\Projects> git clone https://github.com/***/***.git
```

But while downloading, several fatal error occur:

```
Cloning into '***'...
remote: Counting objects: 13197, done.
fatal: early EOFs:   1% (135/13197), 116.01 KiB | 6.00 KiB/s
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: index-pack failed
error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 10054
```

What can I do in this situation? Could any one help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happened to me. That might be because of loosing connection while cloning heavy project.

**Method 1:**
Sometimes it gets solved by using `https` to clone from git.

**Method 2:**
Sometimes it gets solved by increasing the `postBuffer` size.
[Here](http://saugatbhattarai.com.np/storage-location-for-global-gitconfig-in-linux/) is the article from my blog to guide you through how to increase the postBuffer.

You can try any methods.

Comment: I modified postBuffer to 5242880000, but it doesn't work at all. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Did you try https?

Comment: I always use https.

Comment: First try to put post buffer size http.postBuffer 524288000 (one less zero than above). And if not worked than sometimes it work in ssh mode (found somewhere in web).

Answer (score 1):

For such problems interchange https <--> http
I had the same issue so above trick worked for me. There might be problem with your ssl tunnel or firewall on your OS.

*Another workaround*:

`git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000`

You can raise postBuffer to 1048576000 also.

Comment: I hope another workaround will work in this scenario.